# element c# form info

Tags: c#, user-interface, window

I have a program that has no source code. Can I know element name or anything that make me know specific element of the program such as textbox name, button name. Because I want to create c# GUI to control the program automatically.

Comment: Do you know what language the program was written in? And a program always has source code, you don't have it.

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456147/how-to-screen-scrape-from-another-program

Answer (score 0):

You could use [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) decompile the program; you will be able to get any control or class name. Nothing fancy. If you never used dotPeek before you will find great videos on Youtube about that.